# How to add CKEditor for input field ? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I don't know for this question is possible.

I want to add CKEditor when input text in textfield same this :

[image]

Comment: Can you give some more detail?  Do you want to use the editor in a browser in a desktop app?   Or embedded in an LC server script?

Comment: @splash21 I want to use the editor in a desktop app.Same app "Rapid Weaver" Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with ckEditor.

But there is a Library available called "FieldTrip" which provides a RichTextEditor feature for Livecode Fields

With the library you can create an editor toolbar.

The command

```
 ftSetToolbar "font4s/size2 biu colors supersub ;align strikebox lists spacing borders move", "2,10,5", (390,15,"topcenter")
```

for example would create the following toolbar

[image]

[Find some information about it here](http://www.curryk.com/fieldtrip-preorder.html)

Comment: I have added an example to my answer

Comment: how i use this command.                                                              ftSetToolbar "font4s/size2 biu colors supersub ;align strikebox lists spacing borders move", "2,10,5", (390,15,"topcenter")